# Why the content of my page moves to left itself?

Tags: css

go here: *[[obscured]](http://#)*

When I click on any filter and then I click to **"all"** filter, the content moves a little bit to the left. Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because your scrollbar is appearing.

Comment: Thank you Connell!
I had not noticed it. Is there a way to remove it?

Comment: Yup! CSS overflow tag can hide the scrollbar. Have a look at them.

Answer (score 1):

I think vertical scroll bar display when clicked on the all filter. that's problem.